# How do I compile a project for both .Net 3.5 and 4 at the same time

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I need to compile a project for both .Net 3.5 and .Net 4.0. What is the most low-friction way of doing this? If I reference this project from another assembly, how do I determine which runtime is being targeted? Or should I just reference binaries directly?

Comment: Are there actual differences is your code or in what dlls you reference when targeting different platforms?

Comment: Why do you need to compile as .NET 4 if you do not use any .NET4 features in your code? A .NET4 project can use your .NET 3.5 compiled binaries without any problems.

Comment: No, there are no differences in code. All assemblies reference 2.0-version libs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do this simply by having two csproj files. Then I can set the version, references, build-symbols, etc easily. To avoid having to maintain the file list in both, I use a blanket include - i.e.

I have (in the secondary .csproj):

```
<Compile Include="..\TheMainProject\**\*.cs" />
```

This says "compile all .cs files in *and under* ..\TheMainProject".

Comment: Thanks, I think that's what I'll go for.

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage multi-targeting feature.

Basically you will end up with something like that:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectsToBuild)" 
         Properties="TargetFrameworkVersion=$(CustomTargetFrameworkVersion)" />
```

See for more details:

- [Multi-Targeting : How does it work?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2006/11/15/multi-targeting-how-does-it-work.aspx)
- [Using MSBuild to Target Specific .NET Framework Versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383796%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

why would you need that ?

With the post/pre build task you can run msbuild to target a different framework, see the argument "toolversion"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx

MSBuild.exe MyProject.proj /ToolsVersion:4.0

and have a look at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee395432.aspx

But still I don't see any situation where I'd need that.

Comment: There is a similar situation when targeting the full runtime, silverlight, monodroid,... Or of course if your code differs a bit between .net version. Perhaps adding a feature only supported on new versions of the framework.