# VS2010 Sharing Projects Between .Net Framework Versions

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have 2 Visual Studio 2010 solutions and I need to share a project between them. However, one of the solutions needs to build against .Net 3.5 and the other against 4.0.

If I change the Targeted Framework in one of the solutions, obviously this updates the project in the other and I can no longer compile the solution. Is there a way I can set the project to compile against different versions depending on which solution I'm using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *solution* doesn't build against a particular framework version - a *project* does. So it sounds like you should make your shared project target .NET 3.5, and you can still add a reference to this from a 4.0 project in the solution which requires that. So you'll have:

```
Application1 (3.5)      Application2 (4.0)
      \                    /
       \                  /
        \                /
         \              /
       Class library (3.5)
```

Comment: This is originally what I tried, but the 4.0 application would not compile. The errors related to not being able to find the classes in the shared library. At the moment I've followed the advice in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074946/how-do-i-compile-a-project-for-both-net-3-5-and-4-at-the-same-time but just wanted to know whether there was a cleaner solution than having two separate project files.

Comment: @AdamRodger: It *should* work - I do this all the time. Please post the *exact* problem as part of your question.

Comment: Sorry, this does work. When I changed the shared project to use 3.5 I needed to delete the references from the Application projects and re-add them again. Before I deleted them the compilation failed as the classes weren't found.